# Stream live audio to website without Flash

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, audio-streaming

I'm trying to find out what libraries there are out there for streaming live audio to a website.

The current technology stack that I'd like to stay within is...

MVC3/C#
HTML/HTML5

Basically, I'm wanting to build something that will allow the end user to have nothing but their (modern) browser installed and stream the audio.  If possible I'd prefer that the same end user interface support previously recorded content as well.

As far as the input side of things I don't care what it uses as long as it's a .net/c# based technology or if not .net/c# I'd need it to be pre-built and capable of sending to a .net endpoint.

*I have searched on SO for this topic and have found several posts on the subject, but most were extremely vague and didn't fit within the confines of the tech stack that I have in use (java/flash/etc) so please if you manage to find out be sure that it is actually inline with the question before you link it!*

Comment: What browsers are you looking to target?

Comment: @JordaanMylonas any browser that supports it...  The target audience will be youth aged individuals and their parents so preferably smart phones and newer versions of Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari.  Basically as long as it doesn't require a plugin install on the client then they can upgrade if they don't have it (with the exception of mobile). I'd prefer that it's not a Silverlight solution for the mobile aspect if possible.

Comment: You can use <audio> tag, and stream in base64 audio via ajax requests. This will work on every modern browser, but not on IE8 or earlier. Depending on the speed you have available, you might be able to get away with a single request every few seconds, streaming in enough content to fill the space between request returns.

I've not coded this myself, but if nobody has answered by then, I'll do some experiments tomorrow and post the results

Comment: He doesn't use live data, but a similar concept is shown here: http://acko.net/blog/javascript-audio-synthesis-with-html-5/

Comment: "Stream live audio to a website" What do you mean by this?  Are you trying to record audio from the client end and send it to your server?  Or the other way around?

Comment: @brad the answer is yes... I will need a client to send the audio to server and then I'll need an end point that streams the audio from the server to the end user.

Comment: @JordaanMylonas are you more or less suggesting a pagination type system but for audio?

Comment: @Jared, What are your latency requirements?  How many will be on the receiving end of such a stream?  What are you building?  A voice conferencing system?

Comment: @Brad It's actually just an internal tool/service for a youth group retreat that I'm on the board for.  Basically youth give talks and I'm wanting to provide a means for certain people (mainly parents) to listen in that can't make it to the events.  Latency isn't a huge issue a couple minutes wouldn't be any big deal, but I would like the stream to be as close to real time as possible.

Comment: @Jared, In that case, I would strongly suggest considering SHOUTcast/Icecast.  Playing back audio on a web page with or without Flash isn't a big deal at all.  Recording and encoding audio on the client side is.  You effectively have two entirely independent problems, and you will only solve them by looking at it that way.  Consider setting up the source end with a simple encoder such as Edcast, and you'll have this up and running in minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you start here at the [W3Schools - HTML5 Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp) page and implement a C# handler that returns a byte-stream of the audio content for the [source tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp). Failing that, there are a [bunch](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/) of [JavaScript](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) [libraries](http://joewlarson.com/blog/2011/10/16/introducing-thunder-js/) that should be able to help you implement this properly.

The last one that I linked above [ThunderJS](http://joewlarson.com/blog/2011/10/16/introducing-thunder-js/), looks promising only because of the introductory line:

> Thunder works its magic by creating HTML5 Audio elements with a src value containing a base64 data URI.

You could also check out similar questions here on StackOverflow, because you want to do this client-side so the language of choice isn't as much of an issue...
Maybe start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305974/html5-audio-streaming), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593738/audio-data-streaming-in-html5), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809519/streaming-audio-with-html5-audio-tag).

Failing THAT, there's always "the Google" which led me to [these](http://smashinghub.com/10-best-html5-audio-players.htm), [few](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-html5-audio-players), [lists](http://www.jquery4u.com/media/10-jquery-html5-audio-players/)?

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction. Good luck.